# span calculation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here i'm trying to calculate the values based upon the active span. I've posted my full codes on jsfiddle. Span is not contenteditable. And another important thing is i'm assuming span values are 40. So, if user selected the span it would change into green color. if user click another span `span#returndata` should be 40+40 = 80. if user clicks another span the result should be 40+40+40 = 120.

I've tried below jquery. But i didn't get the result..

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m89L4/)

**jQuery**

```
$(".text").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(function(){
        $('span#text').click(function(){
            value = 40;
            var t = ('span#text').value;
            var total = (t+t);
            $('span#returndata').val(total);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You have many errors in that code. To begin with, use `.nameOfTheClass `to select an element by class. Then, don't add a binding at each click and there's no reason to use `$(function` there. And you should parse your numbers.

Comment: Why using ready handler inside click handler??? And why nesting click handler inside another click handler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I updated your jFiddle to make it work. http://jsfiddle.net/m89L4/6/

It is better to recalculate the value everytime a user clicks based upon the number of seats chosen because you may get inconsistencies otherwise.

JS Code

```
$(".text").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var count = $('.selected').length;
    var value = 40;
    $('.returndata').text(value*count);
});
```

Comment: i have a another doubt. i have another div inside the same span classes. But that values are 80. How to do that? Here is a updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m89L4/19/

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle to be totally flexible with the values: http://jsfiddle.net/m89L4/21/ Just add a data-value attribute to every seat and set it to the value the seat should represent. The script iterates over every selected seat and adds its value to the total value, which will be printed on screen. Hope i could help you.

Comment: Thanks. its working. i'm always trying something. But, it doesn't works. You really replied me very fastly. May i know How many years you have experience in this field?

Comment: You're welcome. I have about 6 years of experience in web development.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(".text").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            value = 40;
            var t = parseInt($(this).text(),10);
            var total = parseInt(value+t);
            $('span.returndata').text(total);   
})
```